# jQuery - jeditable on href click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Im using jeditable on a project of mine to edit text on a final overview page.

I also have a href to the side of it that says edit, I would like to be able to click on the href to edit the field as well as clicking the text itself.

The code i have to run the plugin normally is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.editable').editable('/step-five/edit_value',{
        style  : "inherit",
    });
});
</script>
```

this works perfect for clicking on the actual text, but im unsure how i would edit by clicking a href.

Any help would be great.

Cheeers,

Answer (score 0):

You could set click handler on your edit button to trigger a click on another element if the plugin API doesn't offer a solution.

Assume edit button is end of a table row and element you want to target is in previous td

```
$('.edit_btn').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().find('.editable').click();
    return false;
});
```